# Why doesn't TypeScript support function type parameter inference?

Tags: typescript

Let's say we're given a function like this:

```js
declare function doCoolThing(param: string): number
```

We can use it in our own function like this:

```js
function doItTyped(a: string): number {
    return doCoolThing(a)
}
```

TypeScript can infer the return type for us:

```js
function doItTypedParameterOnly(a: string) {
    return doCoolThing(a)
}
```

But it can't infer the type of parameter `a`:

```js
function doItNoType(a) {
//                 ^^^ Error: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    return doCoolThing(a)
}
```

Why is this feature not supported in TypeScript?

- Is it an impossible problem to solve?

  - [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/) seems to have done it.
  - TypeScript tooling can [infer the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/3-7/fixits/infer-from-usage-changes.ts.html) ("Quick Fix..." -> "Infer parameter types from usage").
- Or is it just a hard problem that hasn't been prioritized by the TypeScript team?

I do recognize there is a lot of value in explicitly typing function parameters,
and there are some cases that an inferred type would be broader than desirable,
but it would also be cool to demonstrate a full-bodied work of TypeScript code that was strongly typed but did not specify any types explicitly.

Here's a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgSSgFQJ4AcCmyAFAIYBciAzlAE4xgDmAlBWCALYBG+NiA3gChEwxDXxQQNJKgDCcOABtMAC3oNSTAQF8BA0JFgIU6LHkIAFEjRLtxPAPJgF2UhWp1GTfkJFiJU4zlFFTUNbV19aHhpEwA5OBwCDW8RUXFJGKClVUYwnT1wKKNUDABxfDAeGAgAHkwAPldETC9BVL8MwPls0JJNfOR8CAUrfERIw0zukNzcKxs3WjUWRDYuHgEgA) with a couple of these ideas together.

Now getting a little bit off-topic for SO... Has someone already implemented this somewhere for TypeScript (e.g. a code generation library) that I haven't managed to find? Or is there some black magic way to get this to work?

Comment: How would it infer the type if there were no callers to it yet?

Comment: "but it would also be cool to demonstrate a full-bodied work of TypeScript code that was strongly typed but did not specify any types explicitly." - **no, it wouldn't**. It would be an immense pain to read (without an IDE) because human readers have no idea what the type _actually_ are.

Comment: Also, what you're suggesting is basically this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system - it does have its uses, but "implicit" type inference at a contract boundary (such as a function signature in a statically typed environment) is not one of them.

Comment: You are looking for `F#`